# Angular 2, custom validation messages with parameters

Tags: validation, angular, angular-validation

I'm just starting with JS/Typescript and Angular 2 and I'm struggling with the following.

```
export function MinImageDimensionsValidator(minWidth: number, minHeight: number): ValidatorFn {

return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {

        // it's an image control where a user uploads an image.
        // the whole image related code has been removed for better readability. 
        //Just assume that 'actualWidth' holds the actual width of the image

        if(actualWidth < minWidth) {
           return { valid: false };
        }

        return null;
};
```

}

this is just a very basic example of a validator factory.

All the examples I found just wrote the validation messages/errors directly in the template (I'm using template forms)

Is it possible to "tie" the validation messages to the validator itself and use parameters with it?

like:

```
'Min width has to be 100. you supplied ' + actualWidth
```

this would be returned from the validator itself.

or is there another way (apart from storing everything in variables somewhere) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ValidatorFn` should return a `{[k:string]:any}`, so it's as easy as this :

```js
export function MinImageDimensionsValidator(minWidth: number, minHeight: number): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
    if (actualWidth < minWidth) {
      return {
        myValidator: `Min width has to be ${minWidth}. you supplied ${actualWidth}`
      };
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

then you can access this error like `myFormControl.errors.myValidator`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can return any object from the validator. In your case it could be something like

```
return { minImageDimensions: { min: minWidth, value: actualWidth } }
```

When displaying field validation errors, you can do this:

```
<input #myField="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="...">
<span *ngIf="myField.errors.minImageDimensions">
    Min width has to be {{ myField.errors.minImageDimensions.min }}.
    You supplied {{ myField.errors.minImageDimensions.value }}.
</span>
```

Or even better use some localization and messages with parameters. You can make a component that will take a field object and display all kinds of error messages you use in your application according to the myField.errors object.